# Can't get additional items from url

Tags: regex, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping few items from [this site](http://zoomer.ge/index.php?cid=35&act=search&category=1&search_type=mobile), but it grabs items only from the first product and doesn't loop further. I know I'm doing simple stupid mistake, but if you can just point out where I got this wrong, I'll appreciate it.

Here is the spider:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re 

from zoomer.items import ZoomerItem


class ZoomSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "zoomSp"
    allowed_domains = ["zoomer.ge"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://zoomer.ge/index.php?cid=35&act=search&category=1&search_type=mobile"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//div[@class="productContainer"]/div[5]')
        items = []
        for t in titles:
            item = ZoomerItem()
            item["brand"] = t.xpath('//div[@class="productListContainer"]/div[3]/text()').re('^([\w, ]+)')
            item["price"] = t.xpath('//div[@class="productListContainer"]/div[4]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            item["model"] = t.xpath('//div[@class="productListContainer"]/div[3]/text()').re('\s+(.*)$')[0].strip()

            items.append(item)

        return(items)
```

P.S. Also can't get regex for "brand" string to get only the first word "Blackberry" from the string:

"BlackBerry P9981 Porsche Design".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<div/>` element with the class `productContainer` is just a container and only appears one time, thus it is not repeating. The repeating element which you want to iterate over is the one with the class `productListContainer`.

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    titles = sel.xpath('//div[@class="productContainer"]/div[5]/div[@class="productListContainer"]')
    items = []
    for t in titles:
        item = ZoomerItem()
        item["brand"] = t.xpath('div[3]/text()').re('^([\w\-]+)')
        item["price"] = t.xpath('div[@class="productListPrice"]/div/text()').extract()
        item["model"] = t.xpath('div[3]/text()').re('\s+(.*)$')[0].strip()
        items.append(item)

        items.append(item)

    return(items)
```

This function is untested as I am not a python guy, so you might have to fiddle around a bit.

Comment: Apologies for the edit; I expected it to require approval before updating. :(

Comment: @Talvalin no worries, I am glad when you correct my mistakes :) I don't really know scrapy, so didn't now it is XPath 1.0 only. However, I re-edited the part about `string()` as this seems to be also in XPath 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string

Comment: I should have also noted that I tested the code with scrapy, and I get an `Invalid XPath` error if `string()` is used instead of `text()`

Comment: @Talvalin ok, I didn't test it so I am going to change it back once again. But then it is in fact scrapys fault for not properly implementing the spec. I hate when this happens :(